# Chart.js Options doesn't work in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to position legend on right of my chart but options doesn't work...

```
import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import 'chart.js/auto';

const data = {
  labels: [
    'Red',
    'Green',
    'Yellow'
],
datasets: [{
  data: [700, 50, 100],
  backgroundColor: [
  '#FF6384',
  '#36A2EB',
  '#FFCE56'
  ],
  hoverBackgroundColor: [
  '#FF6384',
  '#36A2EB',
  '#FFCE56'
  ],
  
}]

};

const TestimonialSection = () => {
  return( 
  <div id="chart">
     <Chart type="doughnut" data={data} options={{legend: {position: 'right'}}}/>
  </div>
  )
}

export default TestimonialSection
```

I just wrote this file and chart show up, only things that doesn't work is options. Also checked dependency and all look good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the latest version this is the object structure you must do.

```
options = {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
      position: right,
      ...

   },
  }
}
```